# UITableViewCell autosizing with content hugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

What I want to achieve is autosizing cell with hugging UILabel inside it.
I was able to make it work, until I started the hugging part.
By hugging I mean making UILabel as small as possible if text is really short.

I prepared a really simple example of my problem:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=11087347944522931899

After I set trailing constrain to be "500" priority (lower then hugging which is 750) everything was fine.
Right now it seems that sizing cell is decreasing a size of UILabel, but never increases and all height calculation are really wrong.

After first really short cell comes in - all after this one are broken:

[image: problem]

From debugging I found out that once UILabel hits 8px, it will gets bigger anymore and all height calculation are done for 8px width.

I found a work around and resetting preferredWidth after cell is dequeued for whatever reason helps, but I'm not sure if there are any better ways of solving the problem.

My workaround is comments in attached project (line 55, line 81) ChatTableController.m and I'm looking for proper solution for that.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the trailing constraint to be >= 0, leaving the leading,  top and bottom as fixed. The UILabel should then be free to shrink as required. You may need to set the UILabel property `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to tell it when to word wrap. This is an important property when it comes to auto layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, set the trailing constraint on your label to be >=20. This lets the label shrink.

Your real problem though is this method:

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    if (self.numberOfLines == 0 && bounds.size.width != self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth) {
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}
```

You would be better to set `cell.theLabel.preferedMaxLayoutWidth` when you create the cell in both `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

If you comment this code out completely it all seems to work.

You can also make your code work if you create a new prototype cell every time `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called. This is what led me to the above function.

It seems that every time `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called, the reuse of the prototype cell results in a combinatorial increase in height. You see this if you scroll down and back up.

So I would remove this method completely and let the constraints do the work for you. I see the cells shrink when one line to exact size and everything else compact.

Before you set the text in createCellForRowAtIndexPath add the following to make the layout width full screen minus your 20 margins:

```
cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth=self.view.bounds.size.width-40;
```

and before you set the text in the prototype cells in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
prototypeCell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth=self.view.bounds.size.width-40;
```

There will be an issue with rotation caused by setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth. Setting this per cell means that each cell has constraints specific now to an orientation. To combat this you have to reload the table on rotation by adding the following to your view controller:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try the code you mentioned is for iOS7 - I will try to see if that still works there without it and if that works ob Iphone6. Because it without it was failing on orientation changes as well

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Updated answer with suggestion on setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth. Tried on iOS7 and all fine. In terms of rotation, you needs to detect the rotation and reload the table once it has finished. Otherwise you see the same cells. So portrait to horizontal shows short cells unless you reload and the other way cells appear off screen.

Comment: Shouldn't the reload of view happen automatically when device is rotating...? That's why I started with Autolayout at first place :) to avoid as much manual setting as possible

Comment: That's still somehow wrong... when I remove this code, my cells stopped reacting to changing bounds (rotations). If you have this code + you change trailing constrain to be 1000 you can see it's working automatically and it redraws everything without a need of adding any more code related for rotations. But I see that without it and with trailing priority 500 it's working... That's really weird :)

Comment: It seems there is no way to fix that. I will end up having a separate background view and leave textfields as they are with 1000 EQUAL trailing, so they are automatically updating and rotating. I just add custom code for drawing background. Seems AutoLayout it's not so automatic :D anyways thx for help

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Auto layout is automatic on rotation. The trouble is that when you set preferredMaxLayoutWidth for cells, you are fixing the layout label width to that orientation. Rotation does not cause reload of the table just a run of layout. So layout will use the current setting. Added code to answer which will fix this by simply reloading when the orientation changes. This seems to work perfectly. You should not need to set priorities at all. All I have is the trailing set to >= 20 and the two lines to set preferredMaxLayoutWidth for the cell and prototype and the rotation code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend to do is to pre-calculate cell heights by measuring text bounds. The easiest and worst performant way of doing that is using `- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`.

Ideally you would like to calculate bounds as quick as possible. **[CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)** will help you to approach that.

A good example of using CoreText to pre-calculate text bounds/layout would be [this](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGDrawingLabel/) GitHub repo.

Let me know if you need more info/help on that.

Comment: That's overkill... This is why AutoLayout was introduced and I'm trying to use it :)

Comment: AutoLayout is good, but I would never use that for dynamic cells. If you check performance using Time Profiler instrument you will notice difference.